# How to use Apple's swift-format with Xcode?

Tags: swift, xcode

I started a new iOS project in Xcode with SwiftUI and I want to install `swift-format` to format the code as I work on the app. Unfortunately, it seems harder then I anticipated.

The library: https://github.com/apple/swift-format

I added `swift-format` package using Xcode, like this: `File` -> `Swift Packages` -> `Add Package Dependency...`.

And I have no idea why the executable is disabled:

[image: add package dependency from xcode]

Anyways, after selecting the first two options (`SwiftFormat` and `SwiftFormatConfiguration`) I don't know how to use this library in order to format the code...

My question is, how I can run this library so that it formats the files for me?

Comment: It isn’t some sort of Xcode plug-in. It won’t magically operate from within Xcode on files in some Swift project you have open. It does not “format the code as I work on the app.”

Comment: Hmm, alright. So what am I supposed to do if I want to format a swift file in the SwiftUI iOS project created by Xcode?

Comment: Xcode already formats your code.

Comment: Xcode just fixes indentantion. I'm looking for something like Prettier on the web.

Comment: Try SwiftLint then. But it does not prettify. It just warns. Or use the swift format command line tool as a command line tool.

Comment: I would prefer to use Apple's official formatter, which appears to be `swift-format`. I already built it manually, by cloning a repo and running `swift build`. It works fine. I'm just not sure how to add it as a dependency to the project so that other developers that will work on this app won't have to install this formatter through homebrew/other tool/cloning git repo.

Comment: Alright. I think I will just commit a binary to the manually compiled `swift-format`. Kind of weird but what am I supposed to do.

Comment: It's my question either. Is there any way to integrate Xcode and Apple-Swift-Format in order to format the code automatically?

Answer (score 2):

I made it work via Quick Actions and shortcut to format current document in Xcode with `swift-format`.

1. Follow instructions from https://github.com/apple/swift-format to build the library
2. Place swift-format binary to the global path... I did it with symlink `ln -s /path/to/your/binary/swift-format /usr/local/bin/swift-format`
3. Open Automator and create new Quick Action (name it with recognizable name like `xcode-swift-format`) and add the following Apple script to the action:

```
set current_document_path to ""

tell application "Xcode"
    set last_word_in_main_window to (word -1 of (get name of window 1))
    if (last_word_in_main_window is "Edited") then
        tell application "System Events" to keystroke "s" using command down
        delay 1
    end if
    set last_word_in_main_window to (word -1 of (get name of window 1))
    set current_document to document 1 whose name ends with last_word_in_main_window
    set current_document_path to path of current_document
end tell
if (current_document_path is not "") then
    do shell script "/usr/local/bin/swift-format format -i " & current_document_path
end if
```

4. Set shortcut in System Preferences -> Keyboard -> Shortcuts -> Services for your quick action:
   [image: System preferences shortcut]
5. Add Xcode to System Preferences -> Security & Privacy -> Privaciy -> Accessibility (This step is needed so script can send Command+S keystroke to Xcode if you try to format unsaved document, it means it will save document before formatting)
   [image: Xcode to Accessibility]

6. Edit `your.swift` file in Xcode and hit the shortcut in my case `Alt+Command+=` ... it takes a second or two for the doc to be formatted.

Comment: Excellent solution. But I'm having Space in my file path, that's why getting the error. How can I solve it?

Comment: @MrugeshTank, your shell delimits arguments with spaces. The goal is to feed a single argument to `swift-format`. Try changing `do shell script "/usr/local/bin/swift-format format -i " & current_document_path` to `do shell script "/usr/local/bin/swift-format format -i \"" & current_document_path & "\""`. This surrounds the path in quotes converting it into a single argument.

Answer (score 1):

You can use XCFormat. It is Xcode extension that you will find in the App Store. I think it is free. Then, you can access it through the editor menu in Xcode. Of course, you can also create a shortcut and simply use your keyboard for added convenience.